# Controlling Enumerate Nesting Level

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate, enumitem

How can I control what nesting level `enumerate` starts at?

I often want to have the first level of my list use (a),(b),(c),... the second level use i.,ii.,iii., ... Currently I manually set the label for each `enumerate` using the `enumitem` package.

I do not want to redefine the counters `enumi`, `enumii`, etc., because sometimes I want the top level to use arabic numerals.

Is it possible to tell LaTeX to start with the `enumii` counters for the top level, and then have it use `enumiii` counters at the next level automatically?

What I currently do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*.]
\item
\item
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\item
\end{enumerate}
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define a new list setting the labels as you wish:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mrcenum}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[mrcenum,1]{label=(\alph*)}
\setlist[mrcenum,2]{label=(\roman*)}
\setlist[mrcenum,3]{label=(\Alph*)}

\begin{document}
\begin{mrcenum}
\item
\begin{mrcenum}
\item
\item
\begin{mrcenum}
\item
\item
\end{mrcenum}
\item
\end{mrcenum}
\item
\item
\end{mrcenum}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also do

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{\label=(\alph*)}
```

and so on, then using `enumerate`.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve so by setting the counter `\@enumdepth` that holds the current enumerate depth, try this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter\@enumdepth1\makeatother

\begin{enumerate}
\item
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \item
    \item
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item
        \item
        \item
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But remember that by default LaTeX only support up to depth 4 and by doing so you will lose 1 level automatically. So you may wanna set up a new list using `enumitem` package.

Comment: I was unaware of enumdepth, thanks! In the end, I defined a new list like egreg suggested.